# concatenate cell-array and matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

I have a matrix *m* (16x3 double) and a cell array *c* (16x13 cell). I want to create a cell array *S* 16x16, so with the same number of rows, but appending the columns of *c* to the columns of *m*.

I tried:

```
S= {m,c};
```

but the results is S{1,1,} = 16x3 double, and S{1,2} = 16x13 cell.

I also tried

```
S = horzcat(m,c);
```

but it gives me an error:

```
Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
```

Any hint? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert your matrix to a cell first:

```
S=[num2cell(m),c]
```

The `[a,b]` used here is just a short way of writing `horizcat(a,b)`